Blender Script - 3D Cursor management
I'm making an addon with miscellaneous buttons and I've got a problem with the cursor management. I copied a line from my custom pie menu and pasted it to my addon script and replaced "pie.operator" by "col.operator" :
col.label(text="Cursor Snap:")
        col.operator("view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected", text="Cursor to Selected", icon='CURSOR')
        col.operator("view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor", text="Selected to Cursor", icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF')
        col.operator("view3d.snap_cursor_to_center", text="Cursor to Center", icon='CURSOR')

It worked like a charm. So I saved my script and the next day when I imported it again it stopped to work. The button is still here but now it is disabled.
I read that view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected need context but in my pie menu script I don't need to define a context. It works fine just with pie.operator("view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected", text="Cursor to Selected", icon='CURSOR')
Is there a way to add "cursor to selected" command (exactly the same as Shift+S) to a button in an add-on?
